# Рекурсия и переполнение стека

Tags: java

занимаюсь разработкой JAVA программы в среде Eclipse, не столько ради программы, как ради опыта (хотя программу тоже нужно, так как курсовая)

причиной обращения к профессионалам на форуме, есть ошибка java.lang.StackOverflowError - переполнение стека.
ситуация, в которой возникает ошибка следующая:
в первом класе ClInitVisualElements  хендлер для кнопки

```
 btnOperationPoint.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0){
            screenManagement.AddPoint();        
        }});
```

вызывает метод AddPoint(); второго класса ClScreenManagementOperations

```
public void AddPoint()
{
    if (!bPointIn) visualLink.AddToLastPosition(".");
}
```

AddPoint в свою очередь выполняет проверку на наличие запятой в строке и затем выполняет вызов метода первого класса (bPointIn - переменная булевого типа)

AddToLastPosition(); - метод первого класса, с которого выполнялся вызов AddPoint()

```
public void AddToLastPosition(String Text)
{
    String StrTemp = TfDisplayOperation.getText();
    TfDisplayOperation.setText(StrTemp+Text);
}
```

тут и без ошибки понятно что рекурсия присутствует, но единичная - это последовательный вызов трех методов между двумя классами, почему то возникает дофига ошибок, которые указывают на две строки кода:

```
ClScreenManagementOperations screenManagement = new ClScreenManagementOperations();
```

ссылка в первом классе на второй

```
    ClInitVisualElements visualLink = new ClInitVisualElements();
```

ссылка во втором классе на первый

подскажите пожалуйста каким образом можно решить проблему.

заранее благодарен

Comment: Ничего не понятно где тут рекурсия.. мы жмём кнопку, она вызывает AddPoint, а та вызывает AddToLastPosition.. и где тут рекурсия? И что тут может зациклиться - неясно. Но ясно, что StackOverflowError однозначно даёт понять, где именно ошибка и что зацикливается

Comment: я прогуглив - люди пишут, что переполнение стека возникает из рекурсию между классами, репкурсии возникнуть негде, так как действительно нигде нет циклов.

все ошибки java.lang.StackOverflowError указывают поочередно на две строки кода:

ClScreenManagementOperations screenManagement = new ClScreenManagementOperations();
ссылка в первом классе на второй

    ClInitVisualElements visualLink = new ClInitVisualElements();
ссылка во втором классе на первый

и я чота без пульса чо теперь делать...

Comment: Так вы создаёте в одном классе второй, а второй в первом? Зачем вам такое понадобилось?

Comment: а как тогда мне с первого класса вызывать метод второго и наоборот?

Comment: для начала читаем это: [java code conventions][1]  

далее просвещаемся на тему паттернов:  
1) delegation pattern  
2) mediator  
3) observer  
4) proxy  

  [1]: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html

Comment: Товарищу на данном этапе не понять эти паттерны. Ему нужны базовые навыки в программировании и ООП.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Надо создавать экземпляры классов отдельно, а потом из одного в другой проставлять ссылку. Или вообще снаружи, а потом обоим сообщать ссылки на обоих. Например, как-то так

```
class ClInitVisualElements {
    private ClScreenManagementOperations screenManager;

    public void setScreenManager(ClScreenManagementOperations manager) {
        screenManager = manager;
    }

}

class ClScreenManagementOperations {
    private ClInitVisualElements visualElements;

    public void setVisualElement(ClInitVisualElements elements) {
        visualElements = elements;
    }

}

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ClInitVisualElements elements = new ClInitVisualElements();
        ClScreenManagementOperations manager = new ClScreenManagementOperations();

        elements.setScreenManager(manager);
        manager.setVisualElements(elements);
    }

}
```

Comment: спасибо за идею, но я не понимаю кода, если можно, допишите комментарии к коду

Comment: Какие тут могут быть ещё комментарии?? Надо просто не создавать внутри классов их экземпляры, а создавать их снаружи.

Comment: private ClScreenManagementOperations screenManager;
//  ето создание екземпляра класа ClScreenManagementOperations


public void setScreenManager(ClScreenManagementOperations manager) {
        screenManager = manager;
 не могу понять что делает ета процедура,  и что значит параметр?

Comment: Просто проставляет ссылку из параметра

>> // ето создание екземпляра класа ClScreenManagementOperations 

 это никакое не создание экземпляра класса

Comment: т.е. теперь к методам класса ClSCreeenManagementOperations я могу обращаться через manager, прописавв в другом класе


 private ClScreenManagementOperations screenManager;

    public void setScreenManager(ClScreenManagementOperations manager) {
        screenManager = manager;
    } 

elements.setScreenManager(manager);

я правильно понял запись кода?

Comment: Теперь внутри VisualElements у вас ссылка на ScreenManager, который вы можете использовать. Если выставите эту ссылку через соответствующий метод set.

Comment: спасибо за помощь, буду пробовать на практике